# Error in amsmath as primitive \eqno no longer primitive

Tags: xetex, amsmath, tufte

I am trying to typeset (with XeLaTeX) a simple Tufte-LaTeX example (http://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/files/Week5Lecture.tex) and getting an error message like the following:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty:2496: LaTeX Er
ror: Unable to properly define \@@eqno; primitive \eqno no longer primitive.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2496 \@saveprimitive\eqno\@@eqno
```

Is it obvious to an expert what the problem might be? Or should I supply more information?

Edit: The minimum nonworking example is:

```
\documentclass[bidi]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

The [bidi] is significant, I suspect this means bidirectional and provides support for right to left Hebrew.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some more information in the form of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or, in this case, a minimal *non* working example would be handy for studying the question.

Comment: There are also many other errors, which are caused by loading `bidi` too early. It's a bug in `tufte-common.def`, I believe.

Comment: Oh well, I don't think I need bidi anyway. Thanks!

Comment: And I don't need amsmath either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tufte-common.def` file does many wrong things about package loading when XeLaTeX and the `[bidi]` option are used.

The `bidi` package should be loaded last, while the file providing common structure to the `tufte` classes does it in a wrong way.